# Offsetting a rectangle by X% equally from all edges?

Tags: geometry

How can one calculate the offset distance from each edge of a given rectangle in order to draw another rectangle smaller to the former by X percent?

Answer (score 1):

Let the starting rectangle have side lengths $a$ and $b$. It has area $a*b$.

Call the offset that we want to determine $y$.

The new rectangle will have sides $a-2y$ and $b-2y$. It has area $(a-2y)(b-2y)$.

We want the latter's area to be $X\%$ smaller than the first, i.e. $1-\frac{X}{100}$ times as large. This gives the equation:

$$ (a-2y)(b-2y) = (1-\frac{X}{100})ab $$

This is a quadratic equation in $y$ which you then have to solve. It will have two solutions, but only one of them makes sense (the other will make $a-2y$ and $b-2y$ negative).

Edit: Here's a further simplification
$$(a-2y)(b-2y) = (1-\frac{X}{100})ab\\
4y^2 -2(a+b)y +ab = (1-\frac{X}{100})ab\\
4y^2 -2(a+b)y = -\frac{X}{100}ab\\
16y^2 -8(a+b)y = -4\frac{X}{100}ab\\
(4y -(a+b))^2 = (a+b)^2 - 4\frac{X}{100}ab\\
4y - (a+b) = \pm \sqrt{(a+b)^2 - 4\frac{X}{100}ab}\\
y = \frac{1}{4}\left( (a+b) \pm \sqrt{(a+b)^2 -4\frac{X}{100}ab} \right)$$

Only the solution with the minus sign will work. So for $a=1942$, $b=2620.5$ and $X=20$ (i.e. 20% smaller, making it 80% of the original size), you get:
$$y = \frac{1}{4}\left( 4562.5 - \sqrt{4562.5^2 -4*0.2*5089011} \right)\\
y = 117.60259... $$

Comment: Thank you very much
given a = 1942mm and b=2620.5mm and X=80%
The result of the equations gives us 1672.8mm 
However, the correct offset in this case should be 117.6mm 
Did I get something wrong?

$$ (1942−2* y)*(2620.5−2*y)=(1-80/100)*1942*2620.5 $$

Comment: As I wrote in my edit, a quadratic equation has two solutions, and you chose the wrong one. You will always need the smallest of the two solutions.

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani: You also used X=80%, where you probably meant X=20%. I interpreted your X as how much you take away, not how much is left. I have edited my answer again to add a full working.